# speech recognition for windows application

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition

we are trying to develop a speech recognition application user microsoft .net speech

```
private SpeechRecognizer _sr;

private SpeechSynthesizer _ss;
```

this automatically opens up windows speech recognition, and so it will try to detect all speech, and work with it,

Is there a way to actually limit this speech recognition to only work with the application that we're building?
and also, to only to only respond to commands with a certain prefix. 
ie. bob, are you there?
bob can you do this?
bob can you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [SpeechRecognitionEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete Hamlet...

Yes, use Speech Recognition Engine and use `SpeechRecognized` event to get the first recognized word, compare it to your defined prefix (like bob) and do whatever you want to do when it's true.

Cheers

Comment: @tweelit thanks, i may be back with more questions..!  do you recommend any reading material for this as this is pretty new to us? or is it simply best to google